# Don't know how to load data to GCP notebook (Platform AI)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, gcp-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am turning into GCP "Google cloud platform" to train a Keras model using google's powerful GPUs, for that I created an instance of VM on which I run a [JupyterLab notebook](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/). 
I found my self unable to access my data that is stored as a bucket on google storage.
I found [this small doc](https://cloud.google.com/data-labeling/docs/datasets#datalabel-example-python), under python, they define two function allowing to create and fill a dataset. my problem here is that I couldn't install the **datalabeling_v1beta1** module.

I already tried the command below but had no result.

```
! gcloud components install datalab
```

I am new to GCP, so I really don't know much about the terminology, my goal for the moment is to uplaod my set of data to be able to use it as if I were on Google Colab or on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [installing dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/notebooks/dependencies)

Create a new notebook, File -> New -> Notebook

```
%pip install google-cloud-datalabeling
```

For [Data labeling](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datalabeling/index.html) reference